# Perfmon plugin in jmeter unable to collect data in Non-Gui Mode

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to collect CPU , Memory of the server when i am running it on GUI mode i am able to collect data but same when I run in non-gui mode do not capture data for CPU and MEMORY but shows data of request sent.

Comment: Mention the steps you have done so far for Non- GUI mode.Then it is possible to pin point where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a path to where the data must be saved at? [image]

Comment: Thanks , i had not mentioned where to save the result

Comment: Glad i could help make sure to "accept" the answer if you say this was the solution.